# batch file to add suffix to file name into a folder with a condition

Tags: windows-10, batch, rename

I'm trying to create a batch file to automate a process:
i need to check into a folder if files name have "A-" prefix
If not, i need to add it.
I can name the folder like the prefix if this can help!

Thank you!

Comment: ok, what did you try so far?

Comment: Does it have to be a batch?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I have win10. Should not be a batch, i know only this.

Comment: `gci "C:\somepath" | ? { $_.Name -notlike 'A-*'} | % { gi $_.FullName | rni -NewName "A-$($_.Name)"}`in powershell

Comment: Can i planning the run of this script with schtasks? Or i can do it only with bat files?

Comment: Your question says "I'm trying to create a batch file" and your comment says "Should not be a batch". One of these statement is incorrect. Please clarify.

Comment: it's True.My first idea was a batch file to obtain what i need but only stupid people never change idea So, if is there a better way to obtain what i want, why not?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be a batch file, then you could use [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/products/renamer). You can save your renaming rules as a preset and use it to rename your files/folders via command line or scheduled tasks, automatically.

[image: ReNamer - A Prefix]

Once you save your rules in as a preset (e.g. `A-Preset`) then you can use it for automatic renaming via command line:

```
ReNamer.exe /rename "A-Prefix" C:\Test
```

The rules above simply remove existing `A-` prefix and then add it back in. Files which already have `A-` prefix will remain unchanged after a renaming operation.

Using a GUI to configure renaming rules and test them may be easier than having to tinker with complex batch files.

Comment: Perfect for end users! Thanks a lot. It would be great if the rules could be exported to REGEX. That'd be really useful!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple with [JREN.BAT - a regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). JREN is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file is required. Full documentation is embedded within the utility - use `JREN /?` from the command prompt to get help. (`jren /??` for paged help)

To conditionally add the `A-` prefix to all files within the current folder:

```
call jren "^" "A-" /fx "A-*"
```

The first argument matches the beginning of the file name. The second argument "replaces" the match with "A-" (Inserts "A-" at the beginning). The /FX option excludes all files that already begin with "A-"

You can specify a different folder by adding the `/P "yourPath"` option.

You can have the prefix match the parent folder name by adding a FOR loop. For example, suppose you have a catalog of mp3 files within "c:\music" Each folder under "\music" represents an album, and each mp3 within an album folder is a song on that album. You could use the following to prefix each song with the album name, only if it is not there already:

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\music" %%F in (*) do call jren "^" "%%~nxF-" /p "%%F" /fm *.mp3 /fx "%%~nxF-*"
```